# Entity Framework 6 (EF6) code first migrations with models in separate project

Tags: ef-code-first, sql-server-ce, entity-framework-migrations, entity-framework-6.1

Using EF6 code-first migrations, I am able to successfully save models and create new migrations for them. However, my DbContext class is in a `Sharp.Data` project, the actual (Sql CE) database lives under the `Sharp.Server` project bin folder, and my models live in a `Sharp.Common` project.

When I run `add-migration -ProjectName Sharp.Data Migration3` (pointing to `Sharp.Data` as that is where the DbContext is), it successfully runs and identifies changes made to the models in the `Sharp.Common` project. However, when I run `update-database -ProjectName Sharp.Data`, it updates/creates/migrates/seeds a new database located under the bin folder of my `Sharp.Data` project, instead of `Sharp.Server`, where ultimately the application reads the data from.

Is there a way to do this? To have migrations generate/update a database that exists somewhere else besides its own project file? This may be a relic of using SQL CE, but it's my database of choice for various reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass extra parameters to `update-database` that allow to:

- Specify a different connection string
- Generate a SQL script that you can apply yourself to the target DB

Full syntax of `Update-Database`:

```
Update-Database [-SourceMigration <String>] [-TargetMigration <String>]
[-Script] [-Force] [-ProjectName <String>] [-StartUpProjectName <String>] 
[-ConfigurationTypeName <String>] [-ConnectionStringName <String>] 
[<CommonParameters>]

Update-Database [-SourceMigration <String>] [-TargetMigration <String>] 
[-Script] [-Force] [-ProjectName <String>] [-StartUpProjectName <String>] 
[-ConfigurationTypeName <String>] -ConnectionString <String> 
-ConnectionProviderName <String> [<CommonParameters>]
```

To specify a connection string (which points to the correct folder in your project):

- `-StartUpProjectName` and `-ConnectionStringName`, to specify a project that contains a .config file with a connection string with the provided name (1st syntax)
- `-ConnectionString`, to specify directly the connection string (2nd syntax)

To create a SQL script that you can apply directly to the DB using other tool:

- `-SourceMigration`: current migration in the destination DB `-TargetMigration`: migration to update to, and `-Script`: to generate a script taht you can apply by hand

Answer (score 0):

@JotaBe's answer is correct.  But to summise, you need to do the following:

```
add-migration "MigrationName" -ProjectName Sharp.Data -ConnectionString "ConnectionStringToYourTargetDatabaseHere"
```